# Not able to install through Yum?

Tags: linux, fedora, yum

I have installed `Sublime` on my machine after unable to install I went to install mysqld i have got the following error:

```
# yum install mysqld
Loaded plugins: langpacks, refresh-packagekit
Repository sublime2 is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository sublime2-dev is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository sublime2-nightly is listed more than once in the configuration
fedora/20/x86_64/metalink                                                                                                      | 8.5 kB  00:00:00     
google-chrome                                                                                                                  |  951 B  00:00:00     
http://repo.cloudhike.com/sublime2/fedora/20/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
Trying other mirror.
Error: failure: repodata/repomd.xml from sublime2: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
http://repo.cloudhike.com/sublime2/fedora/20/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
```

How do I reset `yum` and install `sublime` in Fedora 20?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like not all your repos are valid and some of them are duplicated.

Have a look at [yum-config-manager](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/21/html/System_Administrators_Guide/sec-Managing_Yum_Repositories.html), at the files in /etc/yum.repos.d/ and at /etc/yum.conf

Answer (score 1):

I just remove apache and get this problem - WT.. :D

If problem with "sublime2" on the CentOS 7

**Temp resolved:**

use any editor

```
# kate /etc/yum.repos.d/sublime2.repo
```

and find all

```
baseurl=...
```

comment old and create new link

from

```
#baseurl=http://repo.cloudhike.com/sublime2/fedora/$releasever/$basearch/
```

to

```
baseurl=http://repo.cloudhike.com/sublime2/fedora/18/$basearch/
```

Here is all files
http://repo.cloudhike.com/sublime2/fedora/